# Two hosts in jdbc url

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection, connection-string

We are using jdbc url like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql`. How could I set second mysql host in this url? If this is imposible, how could I set in my java application (hibernate) connection to second MySQL server?
Thanks!

PS. actually we want to parallelize operations to two different databases. Is there any solution for that in Hibernate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is really about failover/clustering.

jdbc:mysql://192.168.29.20:3306,192.168.29.20:6306/mysql should do it.
see http://lists.mysql.com/cluster/249

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: There is some delay when first server is down. When application tries to connect to second connection I have a delay few seconds. (FYI I have the same two mysql servers on the same machine on different ports 3306 & 3307). Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: That is understandable.The url doesn't mean you have two connection established and the fail over code only kicks in when there is a problem with the first connection.The delay could also depends on what you are trying to do "Transactions comes to mind here" and all and how you have managed exceptions.

Answer (score 10):

an example for Oracle (failover with 3 hosts):

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.200.40.5)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.200.40.6)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.200.40.7)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=OLTP.WORLD)))`

Regards.

Comment: ,what will be the order of connection in above jdbc url?

Answer (score 0):

2 options here:

1) You can write some code which would change your hibernate properties and switch your DB url.

2) you can have multiple hibernate configurations for multiple session-factories.