# MySQL Insert Into from one Database in another of two different Host

Tags: java, mysql, sql, insert

I want to push some values from one database (DB1) from a host (HOST1) to another database (DB2) from another host (HOST2). The query structure should be like following.

```
insert into HOST2.DB2.TABLEA (COL1, COL2, COL3) 
select COL1, COL2, COL3 HOST1.DB1.TABLEB ..
```

I know this will work with two different dbs in a same host. But dont know about two different hosts.

I am using java to perform this action.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It won't work unless you have Federation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) between the two hosts, no, and even then you may have to modify the query a bit (I don't know the specifics, hence I am posting a comment and not an answer). Another solution might be to use Java to fetch the data from one host into a Java variable, and then generate an INSERT to place it into the table in the other host.

Comment: This solution may help [Two hosts in jdbc url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788085/two-hosts-in-jdbc-url)

Comment: With consoles one would use `mysqldump`. One could export to a csv file but then has to copy that file too. So a java program seems simplest - if the databases are open to the net. Maybe there are admin sql "console" sites.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one time activity, you can do using mysql.

First perform below query in source DB then in result you will get Queries that you need to run in destination DB.

> select CONCAT(" insert into test(user_id) values(", user_id, ");") from user_table;

If it's not one time operation, then you need to make both datasource's repository in code.