# Multi url hosts in JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, vertica

We are using a JDBC URL like "jdbc:vertica://80.90.**.**:***/". How can I set a second Vertica host for a separate cluster in this URL? Both clusters have the same table, username and password. The only difference is the host IP.

I have tried to set the URL as shown below but it doesn't work.

> jdbc:vertica://00.00.00.2:1111,00.00.00.1:1111/vertica

```py
    url = "jdbc:vertica://****:***/"
    url1 = "jdbc:vertica://***:****/"
    properties = {
        "user": "****",
        "password": "*****",
        "driver": "com.vertica.jdbc.Driver"
    }

    df =spark.read.format("JDBC").options(
        url =url and url1,
        query = "SELECT COUNT(*) from traffic.stats where date(time_stamp) between '2019-03-16  ' and '2019-03-17' ",
        **properties
    ).load().show()
```

**Note: pyspark 2.4 , vertica jar 9.1.1**

Comment: Are the two URLs pointing to two separate databases or two different nodes in the same cluster?

Comment: two separated nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to specify a [backup host](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientJDBC/JDBCConnectionFailover.htm).

```py
url = "jdbc:vertica://00.00.00.2:1111/vertica"

properties = {
    "user": "****",
    "password": "*****",
    "driver": "com.Vertica.jdbc.Driver",
    "ConnectionLoadBalance": 1,
    "BackupServerNode": "00.00.00.1:1111"
}
```

This will try the host specified in the URL (`00.00.00.2:1111`). If that host is unavailable it will try the BackupServerNode. You can specify multiple backup server nodes separated by commas.

The above solution will only work if the original host is unavailable.

Another solution is, if you want a random host selected, you can do that logic within python itself.

```py
import random
host_list = ["00.00.00.2:1111", "00.00.00.1:1111"]
host = random.choice(hosts)  # python2 random syntax, lookup random if using a different version of python

url = "jdbc:vertica://{0}/vertica".format(host)
```

---

**Note:** The connection property `BackupServerNode` is named such because it is usually used to specify an alternate node within the same database cluster, but if—like yourself—you have two databases with the same username, password, etc., it will also work for connecting to a separate database cluster host.

Comment: thank you for your answer,but i have 2 URL host (1.1.1.1 , 1.1.1.2) and the nodes not on the same cluster outsource

Comment: I asked you if they were different database clusters or different nodes on the same cluster, and you responded that they were "separate nodes". Please review Vertica concepts (https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Components/ArchitectureOfTheVerticaCluster.htm) and edit your question with correct Vertica terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You can set url parameter in spark session as following this link:

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.200.40.5)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.200.40.6)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.200.40.7)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=OLTP.WORLD)))") \
        .option("user", "***") \
        .option("password", "***") \
        .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
        .option("query", sql) \
        .load()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26803031/12101409